# Attribute Override "..." cannot be resolved to an attribute on the

Tags: eclipse, jpa-2.0

We got Eclipse errors (from the `JPA Problem` validator) like this:

```
Attribute override "<myAttrName>" cannot be resolved to an attribute on the embeddable "..."
```

with `embeddable` (maybe also something like `mapped super class`) on some JPA attribute we wanted to override properly, e.g. like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class DaoUsrMod {

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn( name = "u_lmod_id" , insertable = false , updatable = false )
    private DaoUser usr ;
    ...
}


@Entity
public class DaoFoo {

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride( name = "usr" ,  column = @Column( name = "u_created_id" ) )
    } )
    private DaoUsrMod                                               usrModAngel ;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is an Eclipse bug and so you can change this type of ERROR to a less dominant level (we changed it to WARNING) here (for `Eclipse Neon`):

```
Project -> Properties -> JPA -> Errors/Warnings -> Database 
  -> Attribute/association overrides
    (2nd entry:)
    -> Attribute override name cannot be resolved to an attribute: [Error]
```

e.g. to:

```
  -> Attribute override name cannot be resolved to an attribute: [Warning]
```

Took the solution from the [zonacroft blog](http://blog.zonacroft.com/blog/2012/03/22/jpa-attribute-override-id-cannot-be-resolved-to-an-attribute-on-the-mapped-superclass/)